# Performance improvement. Order by creating trouble

Tags: sql

I am trying to improve performance of this query from last 10 days but its not working. Mainly the `order by` clause is taking time to execute because removing that when i executed the query it took some seconds but if order by is included then its taking more than 5 mins. Below is the query-

```
Select a.user_vchr_char2, 
       a.voucher_id, 
       a.uap_clm_pymnt_stat, 
       a.pymnt_id_ref, 
       to_char(cast(a.lastupddttm as timestamp), 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.'),   
       to_char(a.pymnt_dt,'YYYY-MM-DD'),to_char(a.cancel_dt,'YYYY-MM-DD'),   
       to_char(a.scheduled_pay_dt,'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_char(a.transaction_date,'YYYY-MM-DD'),         
       a.descr254_mixed, 
       a.multiple_flg, 
       a.name1, a.name2, a.address1, a.address2, a.address3,     
       a.address4,a.city, a.state, a.postal, a.country, a.pymnt_method, a.gross_amt,  
       a.currency_pymnt 
FROM table_name a 
where  to_char(a.LASTUPDDTTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > :1 
order by a.user_vchr_char2, a.pymnt_cnt, a.uap_clm_pymnt_stat
```

I tried adding `index` in the table which are used in `order by` but no improvement was visible. Could anyone please help. Please be simple as i am totally new to this field.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the execution plan for the query, obtained with `explain select a.user ...`

Comment: Problem in `to_char(a.LASTUPDDTTM, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` Rewrite your query to make `a.LASTUPDDTTM` sargable.

Comment: Without a table definition and information about data statistics it's hard to say. Might be Hamlet Hakobyan is right - you should format you parameter `:a1` to `DATE` instead of formatting the date column to `VARCHAR` in that case; if there might be null values - use a function based index might be the solution; if sorting is too slow you might be fine with adding some extra space in the temp table space (ORACLE) ...

Comment: Also, please note that ORDER BY should be avoided in SQL when possible. If possible you should move the sorting logic to your application layer.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic: that's simply not true. Ordering on the server can be much more efficient than on the client.

Comment: Well one issue is this - where to_char(a.LASTUPDDTTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > :1 look at using a function-based index.  ALso see what the sort area size is.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OK, maybe I haven't said that precise. Of course client machines are usually not as efficient as server. What I meant is that LINQ and similar solutions should be more efficient then SQL Server in sorting, ideally that would also be done on the server - different application server.

Comment: With Order BY the results are sorted before returned, which usually makes query slower. The only remedy would be creating indexes on sorted columns. You mentioned some index that you created. On what column(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a temp table.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM tempdb.sys.objects WHERE name='##temp_table')
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##temp_table
END

Select a.user_vchr_char2, a.voucher_id, a.uap_clm_pymnt_stat, a.pymnt_id_ref, to_char(cast(a.lastupddttm as timestamp), 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.'), to_char(a.pymnt_dt,'YYYY-MM-DD'),to_char(a.cancel_dt,'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_char(a.scheduled_pay_dt,'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_char(a.transaction_date,'YYYY-MM-DD'), a.descr254_mixed, a.multiple_flg, a.name1, a.name2, a.address1, a.address2, a.address3, a.address4,a.city, a.state, a.postal, a.country, a.pymnt_method, a.gross_amt, a.currency_pymnt
INTO ##temp_table
FROM table_name a 
where to_char(a.LASTUPDDTTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > 1
```

And then you can use order by clause like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM ##temp_table
order by a.user_vchr_char2, a.pymnt_cnt, a.uap_clm_pymnt_stat
```

Comment: Why would using a temp table improve performance?  Please provide some proof.

Comment: In large queries I generally use temp tables after I apply index e.g. It is pretty accelerating my work especially when I query the data that have more than 1 million row.

Comment: That might be true for SQL Server (with it's bad locking behaviour), but definitely not for Oracle (or Postgres for that matter). Creating the temp table will basically triple the I/O necessary to return the result. First to read the data, then write it into the temp table and the read it from the temp table again. Total waste of resources

Answer (score 0):

Not related the question of order by, but you can improve the performance by not using a function in the where clause.  Instead of this:

```
where  to_char(a.LASTUPDDTTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > :1
```

Look for a way to do this:

```
where a.LastUpdDtTm >= a start date
```

Answer (score 0):

first if your index was not function based then it wont be used.  Do an explain plan and you can verify.

a function based index in oracle is specified like this.

```
create index foo on table_name(to_char(a.LASTUPDDTTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

next since there are so many character editing functions I suggest using index organized table
This moves the data to the index so it does not require several lookups to load the row data saving time.   That is the fastest index you can do in oracle.

```
create table table_name(a int, b int, c varchar2(20 byte))organization index tablespace users   
pcthreshold 20 including a,b
```

here a and b at end of create clause map to the index columns.
order by does internal sort so if table is parallel this is a huge hit.
alternative to get magnitude of performance for general indexes add

```
parallel 4 (or how many parallel index queries you want)
```

example

```
create index foo on table_Name(to_char(a.LASTUPDDTTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) parallel 4
```

Note that partitioning can help but also slow it down if global indexes are used.  This is only used for tables with large amounts of rows (ex. 10,000,000 rows).  Oracle performance suffers after 1 million rows in a table. Not sure how many rows are in your table.

Comment: parallel index queries is taking a maximum of value 2, and yes my table containg millions of rows. I also tried adding function based index from the query u gave. But its still not working. The execution plan only shows the cost for sorting and no index is displayed over there. Is it really not taking any index? if not then how can i force my index to work?

Comment: parallel  values are limited by what dba set or by core count.  Was your index defined as create index ixname on table_name( to_char(a.LASTUPDDTTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))?  If not try that.  If it was then change query to instead by a test of a.LASTUPDDTTM is not null.  That will get rid of the greater than test which the optimizer thinks it needs to do a sort and a compare on up to all of the rows. Thus the db may think it can do compare on all rows faster and not use index.  Math operations can result in any index not being used.

Comment: after building temptable with lastupddttm set as varchar2(8) I created function based index based on explain plan and it picked it up.  It should be CREATE INDEX name ON table_name(TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(LASTUPDDTTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')));
if lastupddttm is date use as CREATE INDEX name ON my_table(TO_CHAR(LASTUPDDTTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));